# CSS multiple text-decoration

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

I want to have the `<h2>` underlined and blinking at the same time.
Is there any way to achieve this modifying only the CSS style of `<h2>`?

For instance:

```
h2 {
  text-decoration: underline, blink;
}
```

or

```
h2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration: blink;
}
```

***none of the above works***

If there is no such way what is the fastest/easiest way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `text-decoration: underline blink`?

Comment: according to sitepoint, [Conforming user agents are allowed to ignore this value, since blinking content can be detrimental to a page’s accessibility.](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-decoration) - and most browsers are "buggy" in support

Comment: The only reason to add blink is when you're designing a site that makes fun of old techniques.

Comment: Thank you Joseph, but it's not targeting a productivity site, it's just for personal use. And either way someone might want to have both underline and line-through.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to space separate them:

```
text-decoration: underline overline line-through;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PamjT/

Comment: This is the syntactically-correct way, but I assume that you linked to a fiddle with a different set of decorations for a good reason, and I applaud you for it :)

Comment: @Frederick Marcoux: FLAGGED >:(

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to set `border-bottom` to your h2:

```
h2 { 
   border-bottom:1px solid black;
   text-decoration:blink;
}
```

Please note that blink isn't supported in IE, Chrome and Safari

Comment: A bottom border will stretch across the width of a block element which may or may not be what the OP wants, because it's not a text decoration (obviously).

Comment: I'm aware of that, didn't know you could specify two values in a text-decoration declaration :(, o well thanks @BoltClock :)